# C++ segfault when accessing class member types

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault

This is a simplified (somewhat contrived) example of a segfault issue I've been running into in a larger code base. https://godbolt.org/

Basically it involves a series of derived classes calling into various of the class methods  at each inheritance level. If I uncomment the line in `Parent::doSomething()`, which tries to use a member of the `Parent` class (`anotherNumber`), it results in a seg fault (Unable to access protected memory at address). It smells like there is some sort of class slicing going on somewhere?

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename Child>
struct CallbackRegistry
{
    CallbackRegistry(Child& child)
    {
        registerCallback([&](auto value){ child.doSomethingElse(value); });
    }

    void callCallback(int value)
    {
        if (callback_)
        {
            callback_->operator()(value);
        }
    }

private:
    std::optional<std::function<void(int)>> callback_{};

    void registerCallback(std::function<void(int)> callback)
    {
        callback_ = std::move(callback);
    }
};

struct GrandParent
{
    GrandParent() = default;

    virtual ~GrandParent() = default;

    virtual void receiveMessage(int value) = 0;
};

template<typename Child>
struct Parent : public GrandParent
{
    Parent() : GrandParent{}, callbackRegistry_(*dynamic_cast<Child*>(this))
    {
    }

    ~Parent() override = default;

    void receiveMessage(int value) override
    {
        callbackRegistry_.callCallback(value);
    }

protected:
    void doSomething(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "your number is " << value << '\n';
        // std::cout << "your other number is " << anotherNumber << '\n'; // SEGEGV
    }

private:
    int anotherNumber{777};
    CallbackRegistry<Child> callbackRegistry_;
};

struct Child : Parent<Child>
{
    ~Child() override = default;

    void doSomethingElse(int value)
    {
        doSomething(value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto child = Child{};
    child.receiveMessage(666);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior because `dynamic_cast<Child*>(this)` is `nullptr`, and then the code dereferences it.

Comment: `callbackRegistry_(*dynamic_cast<Child*>(this))` - this returns null (because the derived object isn't yet constructed). Using a `static_cast` worked for me, but I had to add `__attribute__((__no_sanitize__("undefined")))` to make the UB sanitizer accept the cast.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot `dynamic_cast` could return null ptr.  I'm surprised the code get's as far as it does before seg faulting...

Comment: It is not unusual at all for execution to continue for a significant time after dereferencing a null pointer (or any form of undefined behaviour for that matter).   A seg fault relies on the operating system *detecting* that your program/process has done something it shouldn't (like accessing or writing to memory it doesn't own).  Undefined behaviour often has the effect of overwriting memory the program/process *does own* (e.g. dereferencing a dangling pointer to memory after it was released with `delete`, not returned to the OS, and later reallocated and is in use by unrelated code)